# Maintain return URL in live id integration

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an application in which I am using Live Id authentication. When the user tries to access an authenticated page, I am redirecting the user to Live Id sign in page. Is it possible to return the user to the previously asked page (from which he was redirected). Some thing like return URL.

Actually I want to pass some data in query string to webauth-handler.aspx page when the user successfully logs in. Can any body tell me how to pass query string to webauth-handler.aspx?

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by saving the return url in cookie and then checking if the cookie is present to do the redirection.

Answer (score 2):

When the user tries to acces a page that needs authenticated (prior to redirection) save the returnUrl to a Session Variable:

```
Session["MyReturnUrl"] = Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"];
```

You would have set up your Live Authentication Settings to always redirect to a certain page on your site if authentication is successfull, on that page you will simply do the following:

```
//Set Authentication cookie here then redirect to previously requested url
Response.Redirect(Session["MyReturnUrl"]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am hosting my application in web farm, so session will not help. :(

Comment: you could always make use of a cookie